# Build issue after moving to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

After moving to Ubuntu 16.04, I am getting the following error while compiling my uboot source for cross compiler toolchain for arm :

`unknown type name ‘uint32_t’`

Same issue was not seen on 14.04 or previous ubuntu version. Is there any reason for this error to popup specially on Ubuntu 16.04???

Comment: Is your hardware specifications same.

Comment: @HarshalBenake Yes they are same. I think it's mostly to do with gcc compiler versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the issue. Its because of the GCC compiler version. Need to include 
 *#include "stdint.h"* for uint32_t to resolve the issue. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu version but with GCC versions. During upgrade of OS GCC got updated.